# Is it possible to pair multiple BT headphones to an Android device and stream sound to them?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to make an app with the help of which more people can listen to a sound file in their bluetooth headphones. For this I need to connect multiple bluetooth headphones to the device and play sound onto the headphones.

Is that even possible? If yes, can you point me to some documentation? I can't seem to find what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No currently it is not possible to stream to multiple headsets..